# Do I need to install any drivers for 2 finger swipe

Tags: 12.04, dell, touchpad, multi-touch

I am able to use 2 finger swipe and 2 finger tap in my laptop running Win8 but it is not working in Ubuntu 12.04. Should I install any additional drivers or is it a limitation of Ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. It might help if you detail that hardware a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, drivers tell an operating system a couple of things - what a piece of hardware is, its capabilities and how to interpret its behavior/use... And like Microsoft Windows, Ubuntu effectively supports *all* input devices, of *any* type with *every* type of functionality - as long as you have a suitable driver.

With that in mind, Ubuntu will be able to make full use of your touchpad and its three-finger input, but unless your driver has been written in such a way that three-finger input is supported, it simply will *not* work.

So, you're either going to need to find a suitable driver from your manufacturer, or obtain an alternative driver from the Community...

I wouldn't hold your breath though - input with two fingers is pretty common these days, but not too many manufacturers support input with three fingers.

If there's no demand, there's probably not going to be a Community driver...